# Difference between text references and int references in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

The following statement works:

```
SELECT p._id, last_name, first_name_pref, title, photo_big
FROM People p NATURAL JOIN SpecialtyAreas s
WHERE specialty_area_1 = (SELECT s._id FROM SpecialtyAreas s WHERE s.name = 'Customer Service')
ORDER BY last_name, first_name_pref;
```

Yet, this one doesn't:

```
SELECT p._id, last_name, first_name_pref, title, photo_big
FROM People p NATURAL JOIN Offices o
WHERE office = (SELECT o._id FROM Offices o WHERE o.name = 'Beadle County')
ORDER BY p.last_name, p.first_name_pref;
```

The only difference I can find between the two tables is that `People.office` is marked as `INTEGER REFERENCES "Offices._id"("")` while `People.specialty_area_1` is marked as `TEXT REFERENCES "SpecialtyAreas._id"("").`

Would the difference between data types cause this problem?

Also, both strings are actually in the database.

Is there a simpler way to query the database? The `specialty_areas` query accomplishes what I want from it; I'm just trying to find out why I can't get the same result from the `office` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the data types to match on the parent and child table columns involved in a foreign-key relationship.

Simplicity is often in the eye of the beholder, but I like inline views since they're sort of self-documenting:

```
       select * from people p
       join
       (
        select _id from people join offices
        on people.office = offices._id 
        and offices.name = 'Beadle County'

        UNION

        select _id from people join specialtyareas
        on people.specialty_area_1 = specialtyareas._id 
        and specialtyareas.name='Customer Service'

       ) as MatchingPeople
       on MatchingPeople._id = p._id
```

Comment: So, a column (like People.office) keyed to a column typed as `integer` should itself be an integer then, correct?

Comment: The two queries are actually distinct; I hope I clarified my question above to reflect that. They are similar in that, in both cases, I want to get back a list of people that match a provided string (which resides in another table).

Comment: Just eliminate "UNION" and the unneeded query from the inline view named MatchingPeople. Don't need specialty? Get rid of that select statement. Don't need Office? Get rid of that one.

Comment: Yep. And thank you, since that statement works. I don't know _why_ it works, but it does. So thanks.

Comment: All it does in the inner query (the inline view) is select a set of Ids. You can give the set a name and refer to it in the query as if it were a table, e.g. MatchingPeople.  The outer query selects * from People whose id is one of those in the inner set, since we're joining People to MatchingPeople ... on id.

Comment: Oh, that helps explain it. Relational databases are new territory for me. There's neat stuff you can do, but it's a brave new world in there for sure.